# Tensorflow object detection: ImportError: No module named nets

Tags: windows, tensorflow, environment-variables, object-detection

I am currently attempting to install the tensorflow object detection app on Windows 7 (employer requirement) and I am failing at a few steps from the end.

Basically I get the following error when I run the installation test command:
ImportError: No module named nets.

I have read some solutions on the subject:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/729
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1842

which looks like this:
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:"somepath"/tensorflow/models/slim"

basically meaning that I must set the right path in the PYTHONPATH environmental variable.

Working with Windows, I tried calling this:
SET PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:C:tensorflow/models/slim
And when it didn't work, I created a PYTHONPATH variable in system-> environmental variables.

I'm still getting the error so I suppose that I am still missing something but due to my lack of knowledge I still can't figure out what.

Would someone familiar with Windows be able to point out what's missing?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I made it work but... anyway check my answer below, see if it works for you as well. Sorry if it took a while to answer back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to make it work. I am not writing this as a final answer as it is mostly a workaround and due to lack of understanding from my part I cannot guarantee it will work (and also it might not be best good practice).

Anyway here it is:

As Beta previously suggested, you have to run setup.py, however running it from models folder did not do it for me, I also had to run it from object detection folder.

However there was a problem there, it generated an error saying the BUILD already existed (which was correct) so I had to delete the BUILD file from inside of model.

After that it worked, turns out the path I had set was working fine.

Now if some experts would look into this and explain how and why this workaround worked it might make this a valid solution.

Answer (score 2):

in linux:
add export export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim to ~/.bashrc
attention:you should keep single quote mark

if you work with windows, i guess it should like this:PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:'C:/tensorflow/models':'C:/tensorflow/models'/slim
just my guess, you can take a try.
good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Adding the path to the slim model into the PYTHONPATH variable worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the setup.py it will install all the relevant modules for object detection. The other option is download the git directory. cd to the folder and try to run the module from there. You might face protubuf issue. Try to install it before running the code. It's bit complicated to install protobuf in windows. But if you are not using ".pb" file, then you don't need to.