# ImportError: No module named ... in Colab google

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror, google-colaboratory

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://hackernoon.com/object-detection-in-google-colab-with-custom-dataset-5a7bb2b0e97e) (Object Detection in Google Colab with Custom Dataset). The first line of the notebook is a git clone of the tensorflow models:

```
!git clone --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```

After, they set the PYTHONPATH variable to be sure we can import models.

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/models/research/:/content/models/research/slim/'
```

If I try at this stage to import a model

```
from nets import inception_resnet_v2
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named nets
```

I checked and nets folder and nets/inception_resnet_v2.py file are there (in models/research/slim folder). I suspect that it's related to the colab naming convention because the pwd command gives:

```
/root/models/research
```

I substituted content for root in the above command but it does not work either. Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599174/importerror-no-module-named-object-detection-builders-in-colab-google) posted a similar question but the only answer refers to tensorflow issue [1832](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1832) which is not the problem here. Can someone help?

EDIT: operating system is Linux-4.14.79+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic

Comment: print os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] for debugging purpose after os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/models/research/:/content/models/research/slim/'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python process reads the value of `PYTHONPATH` at startup, so modifying that environment variable while the process is already running will not change where that process looks for packages. You should instead adjust the value of `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.extend(['/content/models/research/', '/content/models/research/slim/'])
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, it works now (though I had to change content for root).

Comment: Strangely enough, I started a new colab python 2.7 notebook and error is still there, even after sys.path.extend command.

Comment: Did you clone the git repo again in the new runtime?

Comment: @Patrick I'm running into a similar problem trying both "content" and "root". Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: Actually, for me, the following worked: `os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ":/content/drive/My Drive/PATH/TO/FOLDER"`. I had done a dumb thing, which I'll post here in case it saves anyone else. When importing, let's say `from x import y` you need to set in the path the parent directory of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on your operation system, Linux or Windows. Someone has already asked the same question: tutorialTensorflow object detection: ImportError: No module named nets. [Tensorflow object detection: ImportError: No module named nets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036496/tensorflow-object-detection-importerror-no-module-named-nets)
If you use Windows, changing the PYTHONPATH may not work. Here is a try.
First, run the file `setup.py`.

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

and it may give you a waring`error: could not create 'build'` (because the file has already existed). Because there is a file named "build" in what you git clone. However, the command "build" and "install" need to make a new folder named "build" . I do not know what the file "build" is used for, so I choose to move the file to another directory and use the command above, and it will work.

Comment: I didn't know that Colab can be run under Windows. Anyway, answer is Linux-4.14.79+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic

Comment: in the link that you provide, user is working on Windows. My problem seems to be related to Colab (but I'm not sure)

Answer (score 0):

```
%cd /content/models/research/slim
!python setup.py build
!python setup.py install
%cd /content/models/research/deeplab
```

doing this got me solved...